# How to find created mssql schema in DBeaver?

Tags: sql-server, schema, dbeaver

I have created new database and new schema.

```
CREATE DATABASE banks_db;

CREATE SCHEMA Chains;
```

Database was created, but not schema, and when I try to create it one more time I get error:

`SQL Error [2714] [S0001]: There is already an object named 'Chains' in the database.`

And as you can see on screen (even after refresh), there is no my schema.

[image]

So, how can I create new schema?

Comment: If you want to create the schema in the banks_db database, you probably need to `use banks_db` first...

Comment: Doesn't work, but this should work even without this `use`

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the connection and tick "Show All Schemas" otherwise you will only see dbo
[image: Edit Connection]

Answer (score 0):

This batch

```
CREATE DATABASE banks_db;

CREATE SCHEMA Chains
```

will create Chains in the current database, not banks_db.  Try something like:

```
CREATE DATABASE banks_db;
go
use banks_db;
go
CREATE SCHEMA Chains;
```